# Disable docker container log configuration in Chef

Tags: java, docker, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Through Chef cookbook, I am creating the Docker container I want to disable the docker container log because I have my own application log, I have included the code based on [this URL](https://www.sumologic.com/blog/code/new-docker-logging-drivers/) .But even after including this configuration docker container logs are created.
Please help to solve this.

```
# Run container exposing ports
docker_container node['docker']['image'] do
  repo node['docker']['repo']
  port '80:8080'
  env ["DOCKER_OPTS=--log-driver=none"]#Disabling the log here not working
  command 'env'
  tag node['docker']['tag']
  action :run
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
# Run container exposing ports
docker_container node['docker']['image'] do
  repo node['docker']['repo']
  port '80:8080'
  log_driver 'none'
  log_opts ['max-size=10m', 'max-file=3']
  command 'env'
  tag node['docker']['tag']
  action :run
end
```

For further information, check this link: https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker#docker_container

Comment: Hi, thanks which works,But If I want to pass these options ( --log-opt max-size=10m --log-opt max-file=3) to rotate logs where and How to use them?

Comment: Check my edit @sunleo, I added it there. Validate the answer if it was helpful for you.